# Ratio of $x$ to that of $y$

Tags: notation, ratio

When someone asks for the ratio of $x$ to that of $y$, is that $\dfrac{y}{x}$ or $\dfrac{x}{y}$? It seems like it should be the second one but my book claims it is the first one.

Comment: Could be either depending on conventions.

Comment: When you phrase it like that "ratio of $x$ to that of $y$", then I agree with the book (hesitantly). Except people usually don't say that (I think). We usually say the ratio of $x$ to $y$ which would be $\frac{x}{y}$. I think Wikipedia agrees with us: [Ratios.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio).

Comment: More than ambiguous, to me "the ratio of $x$ to *that* of $y$" sounds grammatically wrong. To take a ratio you need two quantities, so you can't have "the ratio of $x$ to *the ratio* of $y$", because there is no such thing as "the ratio of $y$"...

Comment: My question is coming from this question: A cube is inscribed in a sphere of radius r. Find the ratio of the volume of the cube to that of the sphere.

Comment: "His salary compared to mine is 4 to 1"  "My salary to his is 4 times as small."?  Could vary in context.  x/y makes more sense to me and seems more mathematically defendable but .. hey, what do I know?  I'd simply avoid the phrase completely as appearing to lack consistancy and rigor.

Comment: "Find the ratio of the volume of the cube to that of the sphere."  I, personally would interpret that as CUBE/SPHERE.  But I'd, for aesthetics, prefer to present sphere/cube (as the ratio > 1 that way) and I'd distinctly write it as "r = volume_Sphere/volume_Cube = whatever" to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

In your comment you say (emphasis mine):

> My question is coming from this question: A cube is inscribed in a sphere of radius r. *Find the ratio of the volume of the cube to **that** of the sphere*.

This is somewhat different from what you ask in your question. Indeed, here *that* refers to the *volume*, not to the ratio. If $V_C$ is the volume of the cube and $V_S$ is the volume of the sphere, the question is asking you to compute *the ratio of $V_C$ to $V_S$*.
To me — and to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology), too — this means that you need to compute
$$
\frac{V_C}{V_S}.
$$

Comment: The solution says that it is actually $\dfrac{V_s}{V_c}$. I had also gotten what you have at first so that's why I was confused.

Comment: Don't worry. It won't be the last time you find a wrong solution in a school book. ;)

Comment: It was actually from a math tournament (I didn't think mentioning at first mattered), solution 3: https://sumo.stanford.edu/old/smt/2008/Solutions/geometry-soln.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would write down the ratio as $x : y$, which is $x / y$ for many subsequent calculations, but not all (see comments).

Comment: The ratio of men to women members of a gym is $1:0$, i.e. there are no women members. Are you saying that the well-defined ratio $1:0$ is the same as the indeterminate $\frac{1}{0}$?

Comment: As soon as zeros enter as $x$ or $y$ one can not just treat the ratios as fractions. As long as they show up only for one kind, one might get away with switching the roles.